# hp-setup not working as intended

Tags: python, hp, hplip

Firstly, I would like to inform that I'm a new user of Ubuntu and I'm not much familiar with the usual stuff in Ubuntu. I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

I'm trying to add my printer to my computer using HPLIP (HP Linux Imaging and Printing). HPLIP version is 3.20.3. When I type the `hp-setup` command in Terminal, this is what I get:

```
~$ hp-setup

HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.20.3)
Printer/Fax Setup Utility ver. 9.0

Copyright (c) 2001-18 HP Development Company, LP
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute it
under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more details.

error: /home/username/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/QtWidgets.abi3.so: failed to map segment from shared object
```

Please let me know what I should do to solve this issue.

Comment: download HPLIP from https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/gethplip. open terminal in folder containing file hplip-3.20.3.run and run sudo apt-get update --fix-missing, sudo apt-get install -f and sh hplip-3.20.3.run and follow instructions. It will download necessary dependencies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a mess of local and global python modules.

Remove problematic with

```
pip3 uninstall pyqt5
```

and retry.